# Unable to create pod using podman

Tags: podman

I am new to podman, trying to create pod with two container mysql and wordpress. Below are podman cli command.

```
podman run --name mysql --pod new:mysqlpod -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sdk123 -d docker.io/library/mysql

podman run --name wordpress -p 8080:80 --pod mysqlpod -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=sdk123 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=mywordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_ -d docker.io/library/wordpress
```

I am testing above pod in http://lab.redhat.com/podman-deploy.

When i try to create wordpress container, i get below error

**cannot set port bindings on an existing container network namespace**

Answer (score 1):

The first command creates a new pod and a container.  The second one will join the pod and the existing network namespace.

You could invert the two commands, since the second one needs the ports bindings:

```
podman run --name wordpress -p 8080:80 --pod new:mysqlpod -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mysql:3306 -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=sdk123 -e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=mywordpress -e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=wp_ -d docker.io/library/wordpress


podman run --name mysql --pod mysqlpod -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=sdk123 -d docker.io/library/mysql
```

Comment: i could see pod has been created but giving me an error with Error "establishing a database connection". I also would like to know what makes difference mysql pod created first and wordpress joined it.

Comment: The difference to the commands in your question is not the order of the commands.  The port needs to be published when creating the pod.  That is `-p 8080:80` in the same command as `--pod new:mysqlpod`.